# Regex - Allow one or two alphabet and its can be at anywhere in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want regex which can fulfill below requirement:

1. Between 6 and 10 total characters
2. At least 1 but not more than 2 of the characters need to be alpha
3. The alpha characters can be anywhere in the string

We have tried this but not working as expected : `(^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{5,8}$)|(^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4,8}[A-Z]{1}$)|(^[0-9]{4,8}[A-Z]{1,2}$)|([^A-Z]{3}[0-9]{6,9})`

Can anyone please help me to figure it out?

Thanks

Comment: str.match(/[A-Z]/g).length

Answer (score 2):

You can assert the length of the string to be 6-10 char.

Then match at least a single char `[A-Z]` between optional digits, and optionally match a second char `[A-Z]` between optional digits.

```
^(?=[A-Z\d]{6,10}$)\d*[A-Z](?:\d*[A-Z])?\d*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[A-Z\d]{6,10}$)` Positive lookahead to assert 6-10 occurrences of A-Z or a digit
- `\d*[A-Z]` Match optional digits and then match the first `[A-Z]`
- `(?:\d*[A-Z])?` Optionally match optional digits and the second `[A-Z]`
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ByonE/1).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the following regular expression:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?!(?:.*[a-z]){3})[a-z\d]{6,10}$
```

with the case-indifferent flag `i` set.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGQWjX/1)

This expression reads, "Match the beginning of the string, assert the string contains at least one letter, assert the string does not contain three letters and assert the string contains 6-10 characters, all being letters or numbers".

The various parts of the expression have the following functions.

```
^              # match the beginning of the string
(?=            # begin a positive lookahead
  .*[a-z]      # match zero or more characters and then a letter
)              # end positive lookahead
(?!            # begin a negative lookahead
  (?:          # begin a non-capture group
    .*[a-z]    # match zero or more characters and then a letter
  ){3}         # end non-capture group and execute it 3 times
)              # end negative lookahead
[a-z\d]{6,10}  # match 6-10 letters or digits
$              # match end of string
```

Note that neither of the lookaheads advances the string pointer maintained by the regex engine from the beginning of the string.